# Are there Stack Overflow statistics about tag per month?

Tags: feature-request

I would like to see some graphs about the popularity of a technology for a given time.

Something like `http://trends.builtwith.com/javascript/Angular-JS`.

Comment: Interesting idea, but you'd have to define "popularity" - number of questions? Number of questions and answers? Number of upvoted questions?

Comment: Possibly, you might want to look around [data.stackexchange](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/queries) a bit, and maybe even make your own query.

Comment: I did't know data.stackexchange. I think I can create a query like this.

Comment: I don't see this being implemented any time soon, but FWIW I like this idea. I'd like to see what's trending over time.

Comment: Raw numbers are going to be utterly useless as SE as a whole continues to grow, and 100k questions/month in November 2013 means something totally different than 100k questions/month in November 2010. If I were going to do it, I would look at views per tag for questions asked in the same month (or set of months) to get an even baseline including people referencing those languages via the web but who don't contribute.

Answer (score 5):

Well what I have so far.  But I still miss one thing. I am unable to insert the userinput.

If I change:

```
where t.TagName = 'java'
```

to

```
where t.TagName = '@TN'
```

it won't work anymore

```
DECLARE @TN varchar(40) = ##TagName##


SELECT -- TOP 20
t.TagName,year(p.CreationDate), month(p.CreationDate), count(t.TagName) AS d FROM Tags AS t 
INNER JOIN Posttags pt ON t.Id = pt.TagId
INNER JOIN Posts P ON p.Id = pt.PostId
where t.TagName = '@TN'
GROUP BY year(p.CreationDate), month(p.CreationDate), t.TagName
order by year(p.CreationDate), month(p.CreationDate)
```

I am new to data.stackexchange, so I am not sure where to ask the question about this last point.

I think I made it.

Thanks to all the comments, which [lead me to the query.](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/151455/asked-questions-per-month-for-a-given-tag?TagNam=gwt)

Comment: The string gets interpreted literally, so you need to add single quotes around the variable -- `= ' + ##TagName## + '` or somesuch (I don't know TSQL, but if you put `'java'` instead of `java` as your input, it works. You don't need the separate declare by the way, you can just write `where t.TagName = ##TagName##` by the way.

Comment: Try `where t.TagName = ##TagName:string##` ([parameter types](http://data.stackexchange.com/help#parameters) FTW).